# Give an example showing that $\phi(R^\times)$ may be strictly smaller than $S^\times$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R, S$ be commutative ring and $\phi$ a surjective ring homomorphism from $R$ to $S$.
Give an example showing that $\phi(R^\times)$ may be strictly smaller than $S^\times$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look for a map from a polynomial ring that inverts variables.

Comment: what do you mean by inverts variables?

Comment: it sends the variables (i.e. $x$ and $y$ in $k[x,y]$) to units. Note a surjective ring morphism is the same as specifying a quotient ring.

Comment: Oh, your second sentence reminds me. How about $\phi: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z /p$ for any prime $p$ ?

Comment: That works and should be easy to check. $k[x,y]\rightarrow k[x,y]/(xy-1)$ was the example I was hinting at.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!